# Posting a scan of textbook online?

Tags: teaching, copyright

I am about to teach a one semester course whose syllabus covers two semesters of materials to say the least. (I am trying to change the syllabus, but it is another complicated issue and wont be done this semester.) Consequently, I am going to teach a selection of 50% of the standard material being taught in each of these courses. I researched possible textbooks and, no matter which, the needed contents is spread across minimum 600 pages.

To help students read through them, I would like to post a scan of the two textbooks which we will use with a marking of sections, pages, and paragraphs which they need to read. I could post it say on Blackboard for registerd students only. Is there a way to do it without voilating copyright laws? (Alternatively, I could write a "guide" to the textbooks, with dozens of entries "skip from the 2nd paragraph on page 257 to the 4th paragraph on page 263", etc, but that sounds cumbersome, so I am hoping for a better solution.)

Comment: This seems like a clear copyright violation. You are reducing the value of the work to the copyright holder unless students are also required to purchase a copy or otherwise have a legal copy. It also sets a bad example for students.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no way to post an entire textbook online without violating copyright laws, unless the copyright on the book has expired, or you are the copyright owner.

Comment: Or have explicit permission from the copyright owner, which is unlikely in such a case.